# 2 different page for one category

Tags: wordpress

i need 2 page for one category in wordpress.
for example i have category named "tech". i want it when someone clicks on category first redirect to intro page ( for example :mysite.com/tech ) and see recently posts . then the bottom of page is a button that when you click on it redirect you to category page ( for example : mysite.com/category/tech) and show all posts of this category on it.
both of theme has the different template.

is it possible in wordpress ???

```
mysite.com/tech
```

and

```
mysite.com/category/tech
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s possible. You can make a custom
Page template and filter the number of post from tech cat you like to have in this page. Then you have to create a page with the slug you want and assign the template you created.

For the category it’s the basic functionality you already have so just redirect to the desired category archive.

**For an automated procedure I have the above solution:**

You can split the category archive in two templates

**Structure:**

```
|- category.php
  |- featured-template.php
  |- generic-template.php
```

Then keep the default code in the generic template and code the featured according to your desires.

Then you just have to post a variable in the url each time you are viewing a category, like this:

```
/current_url/?page=featured
```

Go to the main category.php file and check if the `$_GET var` is featured or not and serve the templates accordingly.

```
<?php
if ($_GET['page'] == 'featured') {
  //featured-template;
  } else {
  //generic-template;
}
?>
```

Comment: in this way i have to create a page for each category but  i want to do this Automatically . i want to create a template to anyone can work with it

Comment: I have something that will do the job. I updated my answer